# Concatenate strings provided by a class method in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++11, stl

My problem is rather simple: I have a dynamic array of objects that have a
method returning a string. I want to concatenate all these strings together.

If I had an array of strings instead of objects with a method returning a
string, this would be a trivial task:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "f", "o", "o" };
std::string const x = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string());
```

But in my case it rather looks like this:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(std::string const & name) : name_(name) {}
    std::string const & name() const { return name_; }

    private:
        std::string const name_;
};

std::vector<foo> v{ foo("f"), foo("o"), foo("o") };
```

I would like to use the standard library algorithms as I am sure that those are
efficient and something that I don't have to debug, but this is too hard to read
and understand:

```
std::vector<std::string> transformed(v.size());
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), transformed.begin(),
    [](foo const & f) { return f.name(); });
std::string const x = std::accumulate(transformed.begin(), transformed.end(),
    std::string());
```

The future maintainers would probably (and rightfully so) hunt me down to punch
me in the face for needlessly complicating an easy task, that could have been
done with:

```
std::string x;
for(auto const & f : v)
    x += f.name();
```

Is there something easier here that I am not seeing, or is this indeed the case
where one should let the standard libraries rest, and use the for loop (which is
what accumulate boils down to anyway)?

Comment: I would question your wish: `std` algorithms mostly predate ranged based iteration, and many of the simpler algorithms are best done explicitly, especially now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are insisting to use STL, there is another version of `std::accumulate`:

```
template< class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init, BinaryOperation op );
```

Then your code can become

```
std::string const x = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(),
                         [](std::string a, foo const& b){return a += b.name();});
```

EDIT: Perhaps more copy-elision friendly declaration

Comment: Yes, I just have realized too, edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: Unfortunately, that copies the accumulated string each iteration. A by-value sink parameter *might* be more efficient, it if is allowed for the implementation to implement `std::accumulate` via some `result = std::move(result) + *iterator;` (I don't know if that's allowed)

Comment: @DyP In edited answer, if i am not wrong, copy elision optimization should take place

Comment: I had in mind the [possible implementation cppreference provides](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). There, copy elision isn't possible.

Comment: Well, anything under the hood is in the competence of the compiler and its library :)

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, I think I'll go with this. I will play around with this a little and get back to you later ;)

Comment: The standard says explicitly that the expression used is `acc = binaryop( acc, *i )`.  If you use `std::string()` as your accumulator, you're pretty much stuck, but it is possible to define an accumulator with an operator which does the equivalent of `+=`, and returns a special type, for which there is an overloaded assignment operator which does nothing.  (I've done this when "accumulating" SHA-1 hashes, where a deep copy would be extremely expensive.)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the for loop approach. It's easier to read and it's not something you will need to debug or test (at least not at the same level as if you wrote your own algorithm of some sort). Just because it isn't a solution that utilizes the std library doesn't mean that's it's a sensible solution that is easy to maintain.

Comment: Isn't the last sentence in contradiction to the previous ones? "just because it isn't a solution that utilizes the std library doesn't mean that it's a sensible solution"?

Comment: @mel-: I bet there is a `not` missing in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could write operator +=. Something as

```
std::string & operator +=( std::string &s, const Foo &f )
{
   return ( s += f.name() );
}
```

Comment: You're right, but just because I need to concatenate the strings for what I'm currently doing does not imply that it's natural behavior that `foo + foo = foo.name + foo.name`; in fact in the classes that I'm working with that would be very counter intuitive.

Comment: You do not implement Foo + Foo. You implement std::string += Foo

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how std::for_each, std::accumulate are going to give you a performance win (is your vector even big enough for this to matter?). You might want to do a timing analysis if it matters to you.

I'd go for readability and maintainability over using complexity when it isn't performance critical.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but this feels more like a comment than a full answer.